# On chain complex morphisms

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

The following seems quite obvious to me. Nevertheless I would like to have another opinion.

Suppose $(A_\bullet,d_A)$ and $(B_\bullet,d_B)$ are chain cmplexes, such that
$d_A$ is the trivial differential (i.e $(d_A)_k(a)=0$ for all $k\in \mathbb{Z}$
and $a\in A_k$) and $d_B$ is not zero in any degree.

Then any morphism of chain complexes $f_\bullet:A_\bullet \to B_\bullet $ has to
be the zero morphism.

Seems obvious at the moment to me.

Comment: What do you mean by «this seems obvious to me»? Could you actually prove it? Obvious should not mean anything but «I can prove it easily»...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not true.  Let's just consider the case where $A_{\bullet}$ has a single non-zero piece, say $A_0$.  Then to give a morphism $f_{\bullet}$ we just have
to give a morphism $A_0 \to B_0$ whose image lies in the kernel of $d_{B,0}$.  So unless $d_{B,0}$ is actually injective, there can be non-zero such maps (for a suitable choice of $A_0$).

Comment: A of course... thx

Answer (score 0):

To give a concrete example based on Matt E's answer, consider the following chain complexes
$$(A_{\bullet}):\:\:\:\: \cdots \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_2 \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \cdots$$ and $$(B_{\bullet}):\:\:\:\:\cdots \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_4 \stackrel{\times 2}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{Z}_4\stackrel{\times 2}{\rightarrow} \mathbb{Z}_4\rightarrow\cdots$$
and let $f\colon\mathbb{Z}_2\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}_4$ be the $\times 2$ map as well.

We have $\mbox{im}\,f=\ker(\mathbb{Z}_4\stackrel{\times 2}{\rightarrow}\mathbb{Z}_4)$ so everything commutes.